# Making google pie chart responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am trying to make my google pie chart responsive. The HTML structure is as below:

```
<section id="daily-report-section">
  <i class="fas fa-chart-bar general-icon"></i><span>Daily Report</span>
  <div id="piechart_3d"></div>
</section>
```

Current CSS

```
#piechart_3d{
    width: 1200px;
    height: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#daily-report-section{
    display: none;
}
```

I have tried the most prevalent solution of wrapping the piechart div(`position: absolute`) in a parent div(`position: relative`) but that's not working for me.

The rest of my page uses Bootstrap classes for responsiveness but that is not applying to the `pie_chart` div. What am I missing?

Comment: You should check [this](https://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA) I think.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen of your current code ? it would be easier to understand what's the issue here. We don't have your css now.

Comment: @towkir I added the current CSS. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why did you set the `#daily-report-section` display to `none`. You said you're trying to make the pie chart responsive, but you set it's width to `1200px` and never update it. Is there any `media-queries` ? If not, try with some percentage units, such `width: 100%;` for the `#piechart_3d`

Comment: @towkir The pie chart gets generated  dynamically, thats why its hidden on page load.